# sorry, the maximum allowed clients from your host (10) are already connected" FTP error

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, ftp

I keep getting the "sorry, the maximum allowed clients from your host (10) are already connected" error whenever I try to transfer a large number of files. At first I thought it's a filezilla bug, however I get the same error basically with every FTP client I've tried, including Total Commander under Wine. I do not get that error using Windows. I did try to limit maximum allowed connections for Filezilla, both in server settings and in global settings, it didnt change anything. I did try to switch between passive and active modes (not sure if it's related at all, just last desperate attempt), and it didnt change anything either.

When I try to use native ftp client (not sure how is it called, the one in Places -> Connect to a server) I get abstract "connection refused" error every time I transfer large number of files. Connection is refused for separate particular files, if I click "Ignore" each time the rest of files are transfered perfectly well, so I assume it's the very same error.

Anything I could do? This really drives me mad, transfering large numbers of files is a part of my everyday job...

P.S. and this happens with many different FTP servers. Also I dont get this error in Windows. So I assume it's not a server problem.
P.P.S. I am aware of [similar question here](https://superuser.com/questions/125066/ftp-530-sorry-the-maximum-number-of-clients), the answer provided just didn't solve it to me.

Comment: Are you having this problem connecting **to** a specific FTP server? Do you have control over this server? It sounds like the server has the limit, so changing your client settings won't make one iota of a difference. But more information will be useful.

Comment: I get this connecting to a few different servers (basically every server I need), and I do not have control over the server. Yes the server has the limit apparently, so I want my client to obey that limit or something. And I doubt the server settings needs any change because all works fine from windows clients.

Comment: Have you tried lowering the number of simultaneous transfers and concurrency in FileZilla?