# FileZilla suddenly throws an error: “Response: 530 Sorry, the maximum number of clients (2) for this user are already connected”

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I've been using FileZilla without any problems for some 3 years. However, recently, it's been throwing an error:

> Response: 530 Sorry, the maximum number of clients (2) for this user
>   are already connected.

According to [this question and answer thread](https://superuser.com/questions/125066/ftp-530-sorry-the-maximum-number-of-clients), I should limit the maximum number of simultaneous connections. However, doing so didn’t resolve the problem as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Strangely, if I just keep trying to connect and upload as usual, I often get things done in the end after several attempts.

Does anybody have a clue why things could have stopped working flawlessly as they did? Has anybody experienced similar problems since roughly half August 2015?

Comment: @JakeGould: FileZilla claims that the maximum number of connections is 2. If this is a server side restriction, then where does it get this info from?

Comment: No, I haven't. Except for DirectAdmin but I don't believe that qualifies as an FTP client... I used to be very happy with FileZilla until these complications started emerging. I believe it's the best freeware package available but please correct me if I'm wrong on that one. My expertise on this is basically zero.

Answer (score 2):

> Response: 530 Sorry, the maximum number of clients (2) for this user are already connected.

This is not an error produced by FileZilla but FileZilla shows only the error message sent back by the server when FileZilla tries to connect to it. Often servers restrict the number of parallel logins by the same user to limit the resources used for a single user and often the limit is 1, i.e. only a single login allowed at one time. So this error depends on the servers configuration which explains why you see it suddenly: you simply connect to a new server which has this configuration or the server you usually use just got a configuration change which added this limitation.

If you enable parallel connections to speed up transfers inside FileZilla then it will try to use parallel connection but fail with the error you see. It will still be able to download the data using the one connection it has already established, but it will not be able to speed up the downloads by using a second connection.

This error message should go away if you disable parallel downloads completely.

Comment: Nope. Even that didn't prevent this error! It seems either FileZilla or my server is really messed up... I'll try and downgrade to FileZilla 3.9, see if that helps... (5 minutes later) No, that didn't help either.

Comment: @RubenGeert: So you did limit the number of simultaneous connections to one and also made sure that you have no other connection open to the server (from some other machine?).

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you close FileZilla completely and when you open it again, then you can limit the number of simultaneous FTP connections, [click here](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/ftp/how-to-limit-the-number-of-simultaneous-connections-in-filezilla) to find out how

Comment: Hello and welcome to Super User! While providing links is useful, it would be _more_ helpful to the asker if you posted a summary of the steps involved on the link you posted as external links can go dead / be removed at any time. For more tips, see [answer].

Answer (score 0):

In the FileZilla Wiki, [File Transfer Notes](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Using#File_Transfer_Notes), it states that

> FileZilla uses multiple FTP sessions. One session gets used purely to browse the server. The other sessions get used to do the file transfers.

So if your maximum connections are 2, you need to limit the number of simultaneous downloads to 1.

I got the same error sending files to my FTP Server. The server limit is 10 connections. When I set *Maximum Simultaneous Transfers* to 10, I got your error and a bunch of failed transfers that needed to be resent. I reduced the simultaneous transfers to 9, allowing 1 for the file system browsing, and I got no more errors.

Some years have passed since this question but this should help people who find this thread looking for the answer just like I was.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, I had this error repeatedly even after adjusting the number of clients under 10 (In my case, the maximum number of clients was (10))
It helped me to [clean the RAM cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736937/how-to-clear-cache-memory-on-linux-machine-for-a-user). Then it worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Usually i get this issue when being on a wifi connection - try to plug in a cable to your computer from the router and disconnect the wifi connection. This always works for me when i have this issue